# waf - custom command tooltip

Tags: target, waf

I create a custom command via

```
def spawn_pot(ctx):
    ctx.recurse ('po')


class spawnpot(BuildContext):
    cmd = 'spawnpot'
    fun = 'spawn_pot'
```

and I would like to set a tooltip, but I could not find how to do that. Currently the `waf --help` looks like this (truncated):

```
Main commands (example: ./waf build -j4)
build    : executes the build
...
updatepo : 
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just describe your method/class by either "" or """ """

```
def spawn_pot(ctx):
    """ Spawn Pot Target

        Multiline
    """
    ctx.recurse ('po')

class spawnpot(BuildContext):
    "SpawnPot Build Context Description"
    cmd = 'spawnpot'
    fun = 'spawn_pot'
```

This should give you something like this:

```
the_prompt> waf -h
...
spawn_pot:  Spawn Pot Target

            MultiLine

spawnpot :  SpawnPot Build Context Description
...
```

Comment: If I comment the method, it will show up in the list of commands
If I comment the class, waf will moan about syntax

Comment: To make this clear, you need to use `"""some foo"""` for the class comments to appear as expected, `waf 1.7.15`